# Combining Successive Pandas Dataframes in One Master Dataframe via a Loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to loop through a series of tickers cleaning the associated dataframes then combining the individual ticker dataframes into one large dataframe with columns named for each ticker. The following code enables me to loop through unique tickers and name the columns of each ticker's dataframe after the specific ticker:

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_func(tkr,f1):
    f1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f1['Date']) 
    f1.index = f1['Date']
    keep = ['Col1','Col2']
    f2 = f1[keep]
    f2.columns = [tkr+'Col1',tkr+'Col2']
    return f2

tkrs = ['tkr1','tkr2','tkr3']

for tkr in tkrs:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\path\\{tkr}.csv')
    df2 = clean_func(tkr,df1)
```

However, I don't know how to create a master dataframe where I add each new ticker to the master dataframe. With that in mind, I'd like to align each new ticker's data using the datetime index. So, if tkr1 has data for 6/25/22, 6/26/22, 6/27/22, and tkr2 has data for 6/26/22, and 6/27/22, the combined dataframe would show all three dates but would produce a NaN for ticker 2 on 6/25/22 since there is no data for that ticker on that date.

When not in a loop looking to append each successive ticker to a larger dataframe (as per above), the following code does what I'd like. But it doesn't work when looping and adding new ticker data for each successive loop (or I don't know how to make it work in the confines of a loop).

```
combined = pd.concat((df1, df2, df3,...,dfn), axis=1)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: before the loop create an empty df with `combined = pd.DataFrame()`, then within the loop `combined = pd.concat((combined, clean_func(tkr, df1), axis=1)`

Comment: This works if you add another paranthesis: combined = pd.concat((combined, clean_func(tkr, df1)), axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

You should only create the master DataFrame after the loop. Appending to the master DataFrame in each iteration via `pandas.concat` is slow since you are creating a new DataFrame every time.

Instead, read each ticker DataFrame, clean it, and append it to a list which store every ticker DataFrames. After the loop create the master DataFrame with all the Dataframes using `pandas.concat`:

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_func(tkr,f1):
    f1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f1['Date']) 
    f1.index = f1['Date']
    keep = ['Col1','Col2']
    f2 = f1[keep]
    f2.columns = [tkr+'Col1',tkr+'Col2']
    return f2

tkrs = ['tkr1','tkr2','tkr3']
dfs_list = []

for tkr in tkrs:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\path\\{tkr}.csv')
    df2 = clean_func(tkr,df1)
    dfs_list.append(df2)

master_df = pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=1)
```

---

As a suggestion here is a cleaner way of defining your `clean_func` using `DataFrame.set_index` and `DataFrame.add_prefix`.

```
def clean_func(tkr, f1):
    f1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f1['Date']) 
    f2 = f1.set_index('Date')[['Col1','Col2']].add_prefix(tkr)
    return f2
```

Or if you want, you can parse the `Date` column as datetime and set it as index directly in the `pd.read_csv` call by specifying `index_col` and `parse_dates` parameters (honestly, I'm not sure if those two parameters will play well together, and I'm too lazy to test it, but you can try ;)).

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_func(tkr,f1):
    f2 = f1[['Col1','Col2']].add_prefix(tkr)
    return f2

tkrs = ['tkr1','tkr2','tkr3']
dfs_list = []

for tkr in tkrs:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\path\\{tkr}.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])
    df2 = clean_func(tkr,df1)
    dfs_list.append(df2)

master_df = pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=1)
```

Comment: @GC123 I updated my answer with a suggestion

Comment: To be clear, your proposed solution increases speed and cleanliness but, outside of speed and cleanliness, what I proposed as an answer (based on mitoRibo
 response) works fine? I ask mainly because I know sometimes feeding dataframes to functions can alter the dataframe thereafter. TBH this confuses me - when the original dataframe is altered vs when it isn't. Even if I save the function output to a new dataframe variable, sometimes the original dataframe gets modified. I want to make sure the proposed code doesn't do that. Thanks

Comment: @GC123 I think your understanding of how assignment works and how values are passed to functions in `python` will become much clearer after [reading this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). It's a great read. If after reading it you still have questions, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop create an empty df with:

```
combined = pd.DataFrame()
```

Then within the loop (after loading df1 - see code above):

```
combined = pd.concat((combined, clean_func(tkr, df1)), axis=1)
```

If you get:

TypeError: concat() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Make sure your parentheses are correct per above.

With the code above, you can skip the original step:

```
df2 = clean_func(tkr,df1)
```

Since it is embedded in the concat function. Alternatively, you could keep the df2 step and use:

```
combined = pd.concat((combined,df2), axis=1)
```

Just make sure the dataframes are encapsulated by parentheses within the concat function.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as GC123 but here is a full example which mimics reading from separate files and concatenating them

```
import pandas as pd
import io

fake_file_1 = io.StringIO("""
fruit,store,quantity,unit_price
apple,fancy-grocers,2,9.25
pear,fancy-grocers,3,100
banana,fancy-grocers,1,256
""")

fake_file_2 = io.StringIO("""
fruit,store,quantity,unit_price
banana,bargain-grocers,667,0.01
apple,bargain-grocers,170,0.15
pear,bargain-grocers,281,0.45
""")


fake_files = [fake_file_1,fake_file_2]

combined = pd.DataFrame()

for fake_file in fake_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(fake_file)
    df = df.set_index('fruit')
    
    combined = pd.concat((combined, df), axis=1)

print(combined)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I built on your answer a bit more, making a list of dfs and then concatenating them all at once at the end is more efficient~

Answer (score 1):

This method is slightly more efficient:

```
combined = []
for fake_file in fake_files:
    combined.append(pd.read_csv(fake_file).set_index('fruit'))

combined = pd.concat(combined, axis=1)
print(combined)
```

Output:

```
                store  quantity  unit_price            store  quantity  unit_price
fruit
apple   fancy-grocers         2        9.25  bargain-grocers       170        0.15
pear    fancy-grocers         3      100.00  bargain-grocers       281        0.45
banana  fancy-grocers         1      256.00  bargain-grocers       667        0.01
```